# Source for pure status of those buried on Har Hazeitim

Tags: sources-mekorot, halacha-theory, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, resurrection-of-the-dead

In [this article](http://allaboutjerusalem.com/article/mount-olives-judaism-christianity-islam) on Har Hazeitim (Mt. of Olives) it says:

> "People buried on the Mount of Olives are exempt from the ritual of atonement that those buried elsewhere must undergo."

Is there a source for this claim?

Comment: That site looks very confused, but I would think that it is trying to say that people buried on Har Hazaitim don't have to go through mechilos hakever. They said in elementary school that anyone buried in Eretz Yisroel doesn't have that, IIRC from Yaakov and Yosef's request to be buried there.

Comment: Rashi says it [here](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.47.29?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he).